# Editable UIWebview Scrolling Issue

Tags: ios, iphone, uiwebview, scroll

I have a `UIWebview` added as a subview to a `UIScrollView`.

My objective is to make `UIWebview` editable , which I am able to achieve by loading the following content

```
    NSString *html = @"<html><body><div id=\"content\" contenteditable=\"true\"   style=\"font-family: Helvetica\">This is an Editable UIwebview.Tap here to edit. </div</body></html>";
    [self.customWebview loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

[image]

After making the above mentioned changes, I am able to edit text inside `UIWebview`. However,when I tap on the webview to edit, the keyboard is covering up. I am not able to find any delegate methods to set the content offset of the parent scrollview.

Please help me out on this issue (I want to move my webview frame to the top of the screen so that user can see what he is typing). Also, if possible, please provide me a solution to auto scroll as and when the content is added in `UIWebview`.

Comment: why are you trying to add webview as a subview of a scroll view ? We already have a property in webview class to enable scrolling.

Comment: @ShwetaChauhan
There are other UI elements like UITextfield,UIViews in my screen. I need to put them in a Scrollview to push it to on Keyboard notification allowing the user to see the text contents.(something similar to mail app in iOS)

Comment: @Bharath were you able to solve this problem ? I am having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
(void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.scrollView.delegate = self;
    self.webView.delegate = self;
}

(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView 
{
    [self.webView.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:NO];
    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:NO];
}
```

Comment: I want to set the content offset of the Parent ScrollView (not the scrollview inside UIwebview).